# Graphich magic to convert PDF to png in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am trying to convert first page of a PDF file which is sitting on aws  into JPG and want to resize it and again upload to AWS.

```
Pdfurl.resize(270, 270, '^')
                                        .gravity('Center')
                                        .quality(50)
                                        .crop(270,270)
                                        .transparent('WHITE')
                                        .flatten()
                                        .compress('JPEG');
```

I have writtem above code and this is not working.

Anybody help me?

Thanks